# Why sub query creating delay in AWS free tier SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I run the following query on my local SQL Server, it completes in less than 1 second. However, if I run this query on an AWS free tier's SQL Server, it takes 4 seconds. Both tables have 600000 rows.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    XYZ
WHERE 
    XYZ.milisecDateTimeBigInt = (SELECT MAX(ABC.milisecDateTimeBigInt)
                                 FROM ABC
                                 WHERE ABC.ID = 1)
```

Why is the delay happening in AWS's free tier SQL Server? I have fixed the problem by doing the following :

```
DECLARE @a bigint;

SELECT @a = MAX(ABC.milisecDateTimeBigInt)
FROM ABC
WHERE ABC.ID = 1;

SELECT
    *
FROM 
    XYZ
WHERE 
    XYZ.milisecDateTimeBigInt = @a
```

but I still want to know why is the delay happening in the 1st query.

Comment: Difference in statistics (or other server related things) causing different query plan?

Comment: Firsty the free AWS tier has one 1 CPU and 2 GB memory if I am not mistaken, whereby your local machine will have  bigger hardware spec. So if you run the execution plan, you will probably see a massive spike in memory.